# IntelliJ IDEA find usages of overriding method without finding sibling methods

Tags: inheritance, intellij-idea, ide, refactoring

I have a parent class `P` with subclasses `A` and `B`.

I would like to find all usages of a method `f` of `A`.

So either `p.f()` or `a.f()` but not `b.f()`, because an instance `B b` cannot call `A.f`.

I know I can find

- Calls directly to `A.f`. This misses:

  ```
  P p = new A();
  p.f();
  ```
- Calls to `P.f` and any override. This has too many false positives.

I know there are always going to be false positives using only compile-time information, but there could be fewer.

Comment: How can you find calls to A.f() only, without P.f()?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use Structural Search (Edit | Find | Search Structurally...) for this. Use a query like:

```
$x$.f()
```

with expression type filter `A|P`. This will find all calls to `f()` on expressions of a type of either `A` or `P`. If you have any more classes in the hierarchy between `A` and `P`, you will need to add these to the expression type filter also.

Comment: For more info see here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html#to_search_structurally

Answer (score 7):

Now it's possible to search usages in more depth. Just hit Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F7 (for Mac `Cmd+Shift+Alt+F7`) instead of Alt+F7 and check what you want to search for. In your case, uncheck 'Search for base method usages'.

For more information check out the official site: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-usages-method-options.html